# QGIS atlas generation to make company expansion slideshow/video

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, atlas

I need to create ~98 maps each showing the locations of customers as a company expands over a time series.

These will be made into a slideshow/video showcase so all maps need to have the exact same extent and scale regardless of customer expansion within (and beyond) the extent of the composer.

Each week's customers are currently in 98 separate CSV files.  I could get a single CSV with each week's batch of customers assigned a unique week ID if that is better.

I am unfortunately clueless about building expressions in print composer (and python) so my attempts to automate this process have all given me the wrong results.  I am very happy to share sample files, screenshots, (even the modest fee I am being paid to do this..) in order not to have to do it manually.

Ideally two boxes showing a) the week commencing date and b) the total number of customers active that week should be overlaid and updated automatically.

Comment: Some starting links to look at (while waiting for a better answer): [easyprint plugin](http://darrencope.com/2011/11/22/map-books-in-qgis/) and the [atlas generation part of print composer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#atlas-generation). It is possible that neither of those fixes the extent/scale of the map, however; most such series move around geographically to different features, rather than "moving" in time.

Comment: What kind of features do you have? Do you have polygons with related customer informations in CSV or points with informations and coordinates? Please share those sample data, so we can have a glance at the problem.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Time Manager plugin](http://anitagraser.com/projects/time-manager/). The description says it has the ability to export image series or an animation/video, and this is the approach I would take (and have) in ArcGIS. The date label shouldn't be a problem, but customer count might be - that's been [asked before](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103862/label-changing-with-time-slider-using-arcgis) and while I had some ideas no implemented solution comes to mind. I would say that a single CSV would be more convenient to work with.